# Why are the Yonyx named Yonyx?

Tags: bigbug

Is it a French pun of some kind? Or is it just a random name? No info I've read gives an explanation of the name.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't know the word or the movie. So I looked up.
It says it's a movie about domestics robots: Yonix.
As a french-speaking folk, first thing I heard was a pun based upon "*bionics*".

I couldn't find any related explanation in media or movies DB or websites to back up my post though...

Comment: +1 I'm a native English speaker and "Yonyx" being a shortened version of "bionics" makes a **lot** of sense to me.

Comment: Yeah, this makes the most sense out of anything. Just haven't seem Bionics as much as I've seen Robot, Android, and other terms.

Answer (score 2):

Having not properly seen the movie (I started but had to cut short) I can't really connect the dots on this.

There are 2 references to the word "Yonyx" that I have been able to find.

1. a [telemarketing company](https://corp.yonyx.com/).
2. an Uzbek word for "fire"

I highly doubt it to be either of these though, as the translation only works in English, and I highly doubt they would be attempting to damage the reputation of a telemarketing company...

Alternatively, it could simply be just a word they came up with (as it doesn't translate from French); I often attempt to come up with names for things by taking random syllables and putting them together.